# XML manipulation using perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

Hi i have been trying to work with XML manipulation using perl ( i have tried XML::LibXML, XML::Twig and XML::Simple) but i couldnt read it. I think it might be because of my file.
an example of the XML file:

```
<model-responses>
    <model mh="0x12a700">
      <attribute id="0x1006e">web2dda5p.sicredi.net</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x12d7f">172.25.76.18</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x110df">00:50:56:80:02:1e</attribute>
    </model>
<model mh="0x12a900">
  <attribute id="0x1006e">sicorr-apps14.sicredi.net</attribute>
  <attribute id="0x12d7f">172.19.33.17</attribute>
  <attribute id="0x110df">00:50:56:8a:02:21</attribute>
</model>

</model-responses>
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
<model-responses>
 <model>
    <name>web2dda5p.sicredi.net</name>
    <ip>172.25.76.18</ip>
    <mac>00:50:56:80:02:1e</mac>
    <modelhandle>0x12a700</modelhandle>
 </model>
```

Any help would be apreciated.
Thaks in advance.
Henrique Condotta

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $xml = <<'__EOI__';
<model-responses>
    <model mh="0x12a700">
      <attribute id="0x1006e">web2dda5p.sicredi.net</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x12d7f">172.25.76.18</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x110df">00:50:56:80:02:1e</attribute>
    </model>
    <model mh="0x12a900">
      <attribute id="0x1006e">sicorr-apps14.sicredi.net</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x12d7f">172.19.33.17</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x110df">00:50:56:8a:02:21</attribute>
    </model>
</model-responses>
__EOI__
```

```
my %attribute_name_from_id = (
   '0x1006e' => 'name',
   '0x12d7f' => 'ip',
   '0x110df' => 'mac',
);

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);

for my $model ($doc->findnodes('/model-responses/model')) {
   my $handle = $model->getAttribute('mh');
   $model->removeAttribute('mh');

   for my $attribute ($model->getChildrenByTagName('attribute')) {
      my $attribute_id = $attribute->getAttribute('id');
      my $attribute_name = $attribute_name_from_id{$attribute_id}
         or next;

      my $ele = XML::LibXML::Element->new($attribute_name);
      $ele->appendChild($_) for $attribute->childNodes();

      $model->insertAfter($ele, $attribute);
      $model->removeChild($attribute);
   }

   {
      my $ele = XML::LibXML::Element->new('modelhandle');
      $ele->appendText($handle);
      $model->appendChild($ele);
   }
}

print $doc->toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use the [XSLT parser](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/XML-XSLT-0.48/lib/XML/XSLT.pm)

```
 use XML::XSLT;

 my $xslt = XML::XSLT->new ($xsl, warnings => 1);

 $xslt->transform ($xmlfile);
 print $xslt->toString;

 $xslt->dispose();
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <model-responses>
            <xsl:for-each select="/model-responses/model">

                <model>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="attribute[@id='0x1006e']"/>
                    </name>
                    <ip>
                        <xsl:value-of select="attribute[@id='0x12d7f']"/>
                    </ip>
                    <mac>
                        <xsl:value-of select="attribute[@id='0x110df']"/>
                    </mac>
                    <modelhandle>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@mh"/>
                    </modelhandle>
                </model>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </model-responses>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which you can build here http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<model-responses>
    <model>
        <name>web2dda5p.sicredi.net</name>
        <ip>172.25.76.18</ip>
        <mac>00:50:56:80:02:1e</mac>
        <modelhandle>0x12a700</modelhandle>
    </model>
    <model>
        <name>sicorr-apps14.sicredi.net</name>
        <ip>172.19.33.17</ip>
        <mac>00:50:56:8a:02:21</mac>
        <modelhandle>0x12a900</modelhandle>
    </model>
</model-responses>
```

---

EDIT - perhaps more standard XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="model-responses">
        <model-responses>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </model-responses>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="model">
        <model>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>

            <modelhandle><xsl:value-of select='@mh'/></modelhandle>
        </model>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attribute[@id='0x1006e']">
        <name><xsl:value-of select='.'/></name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attribute[@id='0x12d7f']">
        <ip><xsl:value-of select='.'/></ip>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attribute[@id='0x110df']">
        <mac><xsl:value-of select='.'/></mac>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```